# Opening new page when it is the first time to login in only ? Flutter firebase

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart

I am creating an app and I wanna use to give me some information if it's his first login

**EDIT**

My code works fine when I tell him to print whether it's a first user or not but when I made him return routes it doesn't work.

```
Future<void> signInWithGoogle() async {
try {
  GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
  AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);
  UserCredential authResult =
      await _auth.signInWithCredential(authCredential);

  if (authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
    return ContactPage();
  } else {
    return HomePage();
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
}
```

}

**My Debug Console**

> D/EGL_emulation(17377): eglMakeCurrent: 0xf1162c20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf11fd950)
> W/ple.calling_ap(17377): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getUnsafe()Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
> W/ple.calling_ap(17377): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->objectFieldOffset(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
> W/ple.calling_ap(17377): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
> W/ple.calling_ap(17377): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
> W/ple.calling_ap(17377): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
> I/FirebaseAuth(17377): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
> 2
> W/System  (17377): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
> D/FirebaseAuth(17377): Notifying id token listeners about user ( YJNbeDYPgFSVz5e3xKun6nJe8643 ).

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I got that you want to see if the user is new to your application mean when user first time logins to your app, you want to show some additional information to.
When you call `googlelogin()` method it return `UserCrendtials user` and a you can check by `user.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser`. It returns true if user is new and false if your users is not new to your app.
Hopefully Your code will look like this:

```
var user = googlelogin();
if(user.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser){
  //DO whatever you want to do, 
}else{
  //Continue with app flow
}
```

hope it will solve your problem.
However I didn't get what you are trying to do in your streambuilder and how can you improve this.

Comment: thanks for you answer in fact i added a similar code like that before it was   if (result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
        return UserNum();
      } else {
        return LoggedInWidget();  }  
    my streambuilder is because it was the only way for me to open the app from the main page because it gives me error when i make it open from the login page

Comment: Sorry i can't get what are you actually trying to achieve. I think this is no need to use streambuilder to open main page from login page. Can you please attcah error message.

Comment: there wasn't an error message in fact but it's okay I will try to solve it with another code thanks for your caring 

Comment: Sure, good luck. let me know too, when you are done

Comment: I edit the question because i face the same error after I change the code and delete the streambuilder but it didn't work